# Modifying a string of html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made an ajax call that returns a string of html.  I want to add a class to an element inside that string of html.  Then I want to take this newly modified html string and reassign it to the same variable as before.  I'm noticing that, if I have this html string that looks like:

```
section
  div
  /div
section
```

and if I print it out, I see the section with a div inside.  But if i do `$(html_data).html()` then it only shows the div as the root element.  If I `console.log($(html_data))` I can see the section.
But again, `console.log($(html_data).html())` shows the top element as being the div.  It's as if wrapping the string inside `$()` removes the top element.

I cannot use `$(html_data).outerHTML()`.  I get an error that says it's not a function.

How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: For outerHTML, you would use $(html_data).get(0).outerHTML.  get returns the HTML element: http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: Hey Brian, that actually solved it entirely. The get(0) made outerHTML work. I really  appreciate your help man!